# How to add a daemon.json file in docker ubuntu?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I don't know how to add a daemon json file in this /etc/docker/daemon.json location

I tried with this command dockerd --config-file /etc/docker/daemon.json and it is giving error that daemon.json is not present in current location

Answer (score 2):

you need to create the file first:

```
sudo touch /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

then you can edit the contents of the file, for example with Vim:

```
sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

btw, you don't need to specify that config file with "--config-file" option as is he default one:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

```
nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

---

```
{
  "insecure-registries": ["http://myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
}
```

- paste above and save
- restart docker